# How to simulate a link with JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a link which will act just like regular `<a>` tag. Currently I use `onClick="window.location=''`, but it doesn't open new window on middle click like `<a>` tag does.

```
<table>
   <tr onClick="window.location='/generatedlink.php'">
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

I don't really need right click functionality

Comment: @hop: I put the `jquery` tag the OP supplied back. Who knows, maybe someone will have an answer that requires jQuery. The tag lets them know it's okay to post that.

Comment: @Chad That's exactly what he already has, just not inline

Comment: What's wrong with an actual link?

Comment: @Scott, because I need to link whole row, you cant replace it with `a`

Comment: Sorry for the snarky comment.  Something was going badly on the job.  I shouldn't comment for a few minutes when that happens.  ;-)

Answer (score 4):

If you want any browser-provided functionality, such as middle-click to open in a new window or right-click for options (new window, new tab, save, copy link, etc.), it will have to be a normal  link. The browser has no way to know that you non- element is supposed to behave like a link.

Comment: +1 This is the right answer. @skyisred, you could try to detect which button was down, etc., but getting it right cross-browser is going to be a **constant** battle. Put `a` elements with `display: block` in your `td` elements in the row, so the browser can do its job.

Comment: right click functionality is not very important, I mostly need middle click

Comment: The same still applies: if you want browser-provided behavior, including middle-click to open in a new tab, you have to use normal <a> links so the browser knows to apply those behaviors.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

> window.open('/generatedlink.php')

to open in a new window but it will most likely get blocked by the browser.

You can use mousedown to detect any mousedown event .

```
$('a.dynlinks').mousedown(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    switch(e.which){
        case 1:
            //left click
            // use window.location
            break;
        case 2:
            //middle click
            // use window.open
            break;
    }
})
```

Comment: *"...but it will most likely get blocked by the browser."* Not in direct response to a click it won't.

Comment: This doesn't solve the middle-click problem the OP asked about.

Answer (score -3):

use **document.location**

instead of **window.location**

```
<table>
    <tr onClick="document.location='/generatedlink.php'">
       <td> </td>
       <td> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```